HTTP Headers Empty BEFORE use
This is an Angular 17 project.
I am assigning headers to an object and as soon as I've done that, logged that object in the console. When I compare this to other uses of this code elsewhere in the project, the console reports the headers as being populated.
Code in component;
  followUser(user: UserPostLikes) {
   if (user.followed == true) {
     this.userService.UnfollowUser(user.id).subscribe(data => {
       user.followed = false;
     });
   } else {
     this.userService.FollowUser(user.id).subscribe(data => {
       user.followed = true;
     });
   }
 }

Code in 'userService';
  public FollowUser = (userId: number): Observable<UserWallPostCommentGet> => { //line 137
    this.headerItems = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!).tokens.access
    });
    console.log(this.headerItems);
    return this.http.post<UserWallPostCommentGet>(environment.apiUrl + "/users/" + userId + "/follow", { 'headers': this.headerItems });
  }

  public UnfollowUser = (userId: number): Observable<UserWallPostCommentGet> => { //line 147
    this.headerItems = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!).tokens.access
    });
    console.log(this.headerItems);
    return this.http.delete<UserWallPostCommentGet>(environment.apiUrl + "/users/" + userId + "/follow", { 'headers': this.headerItems });
  }

Console is showing this;

console screenshot
It would appear the headers are being blocked or similar. The weird part is that I am using this code in other places and it works fine.
Can anyone shed light on this? I have had a look at some of the other answers and none of them seem applicable in this case.

Hello! Seems like you are assigning the header to a class field before passing it to the REST method. Is there any necessity for this because it seems rather error prone and unnecessary to me? Why not just assign it to a local variable instead?
